# How to compare nested attributes on Grails with attributes from "outside" of the nested scope using named query?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have a situation where I need to validate a range of dates from a nested object based on the date of my object.

So let say I have one class named:

```
Course{
Date date
Teacher teacher
}

Teacher{
Date effectiveDate
Date terminationDate
}
```

What I need to do is a query with a projection of another class and into the query I need to validate the date like this:

```
le 'effectiveDate', date
            or {
                ge 'terminationDate', date
                isNull 'terminationDate'
            }
```

The issue is that I can't use date because on the named query I don't have an instance of the object. How can I compare nested object attributes against this date?

Comment: you want to use Course date from author in your criteria instead of 'data' variable, right?

Comment: @Koloritnij sorry, I made a mistake there, I want to use my date from Course to validate it against effectiveDate and terminationDate from Teacher.

Comment: You are close. Can you give me an idea of how you want to use this query? Are you looking to get a list of all courses that have teachers that are effective and not yet terminated? Or are you already looking at a course and want to determine if the teacher is effective and not terminated?

Comment: @BryanGCampbell, I'm projecting a third Object (that is not on this domain) that is into Course. It's a named query, so I call Course.myNamedQuery and yes, I need to get the courses that have teachers that are effective and not yet terminated.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is to use `createAlias`. Unfortunatly, `createAlias` doesn't work with Spock unit testing, so I can't create a test to see if this works and I don't have time right now to create an app to test this, so this is mostly a guess.

Your Named Query should look something like this:

```
findCoursesWithActiveTeacher { ->
    createAlias 'teacher', 't'
    geProperty 'date', 't.effectiveDate'
    or {
        leProperty 'date', 't.terminationDate'
        isNull 't.terminationDate'
    }
}
```

I think I inverted the greater than and less then comparisons properly. Hopefully we get lucky and this works for you.